# How to make 3 columns table with Twig in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, pagination, html-table, twig

I am new to Twig and Symfony2. I was wondering how can I create a 3 column table with Twig. My data comes from a database

So far I've tried everything but still nothin works. I found this on Stackoverflow about making a 2 column table, and it worked perfectly except for me. I want 3 columns .

```
<table>
  {% for var in var1 %}
    {% if (loop.index % 2) %}<tr>{% endif %}
    <td>
      <div class="bloc">
        <a href="{{ path('xxxxxxx', {'id':var.id}) }}">
        <span>{{ var.name}}  </spann></a></div>
        <img src="{{ asset(var.image ) }}"  />    
      </div>
    </td>
    {% if (loop.index % 2) and loop.last %}
      <td>&nbsp</td>
    {% endif %}
    {% if (loop.index0 % 2) or loop.last %}</tr>{% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</table>


ex: var1  contains names and pictures from database.
name1  name2  name3
name4  name5  name6
...
```

This is what I have ATM

```
name1   name2
name3   name4   name5
name6   name7   name8
```

Comment: please supply more information, e.g. contents of `var1`

Comment: var 1 was an example, let's say that var1 is an array of data from my data base.. i receive the data i only need too display my info in 3 columns let's say it's info for 3 persons  each with name, address in one cell..don't know how to explain more sorry..in english

Comment: i'm trying to help: you should print the value between `<td>` and `</td>` (p.s. you mistype `</td>`)

Comment: i re edit my post with the code. thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution works for any number of columns:

```
{% set columns = 3 %}
{% for name in names %}
    {% if loop.first or loop.index0 is divisibleby(columns) %}
        <tr>
    {% endif %}

    <td>{{ name }}</td>

    {% if loop.last and loop.index is not divisibleby(columns) %}
        {% for n in range(low=columns - (loop.index % columns), high=1, step=-1) %}
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if loop.last or loop.index is divisibleby(columns) %}
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 6):

Correct way are you use batch (array_chunk):

```
{% for batchResults in result.items|batch(result.total_results / columns) %}
    <div class="{{cycle(['left', 'left', 'right'], loop.index)}}">
        {% for item in batchResults %}
            <div class="{% if loop.last %}last{% endif %}">
                {{item}}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Peekmo's solution is correct but there is possibly a neater way using the batch filter in twig. this filter breaks a list into smaller subsets. You control the size and use nested for loops to display rows and their contents. The example in the docs is an exact answer to this problem. The filter will also neatly handle empty cells. Ie you have 8 values in an array and you want a 3 column table, the last cell will be emtpy

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like that :

```
<table>
{% for var in var1%}
<tr>
    <td>Title1<td>
    <td>Title2<td>
    <td>Title3<td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ var.attr1 }}<td>
    <td>{{ var.attr2 }}<td>
    <td>{{ var.attr3 }}<td>
</tr>
{%endfor%}
 </table>
```

Comment: this is not what i am trying to do but Thanks @Kyrillos i explain myself very poorly sorry but i edit the post with codes so you can understand what i want.

Comment: You're french @Mkfootwo ?

Comment: Tu peux poser ta question en Français, même si je suis pas sûr que ce soit dans l'esprit du site. Car je n'ai vraiment pas compris ton souci. À moins que tu l'aies réglé.

Comment: @merci Kyrillos le probleme est resolu.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>

{% for var in var1%}
{% if loop.index0 is divisibleby(3) %}
</tr>
<tr>
{% endif %}
    <td>{{ var }}</td>

{% if loop.last %}
</tr>
{% endif %}

{%endfor%}
 </table>
```

I think that could work for your problem, you have to open  tag every 3 iterations, and do not forget to close the last one when your loop is terminated.

Comment: it work thank you but the first line is displaying 2 rows then the other lines  3 rows like now here's the problem.

Comment: Yes that's because loop.index is starting to 1, use loop.index0 instead of loop.index sorry.

Comment: No problem, please, don't forget to mark the answer as "resolved" ;)

Comment: So, at first an empty row, and if the loop.last is in the the first or second column, the last row is collapsed. Dirty ^^

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but should print a clean table.

```
<table>
  {% for var in var1 %}
    {% if not (loop.index0 % 3) %}<tr>{% endif %}
    <td>
      <div class="bloc">
        <a href="{{ path('xxxxxxx', {'id':var.id}) }}">
        <span>{{ var.name}}  </spann></a></div>
        <img src="{{ asset(var.image ) }}"  />    
      </div>
    </td>
    {% if (loop.index % 2) and loop.last %}
      <td>&nbsp</td>
    {% endif %}
    {% if (loop.index % 3) and loop.last %}
      <td>&nbsp</td>
    {% endif %}
    {% if not (loop.index % 3) or loop.last %}</tr>{% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```